# Formatter parameter passes as null

Tags: excel, sapui5, formatter

I am trying to export table data to an Excel sheet. Everything works OK without formatter. But I have to format some cells before converting table to Excel. I'm debugging the code. Formatter function's parameter passes as null value. Here is my code:

```
var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({

  exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
    separatorChar: ";"
  }),

  models: this.getView().getModel(),

  rows: {
    path: "/FaaliyetServisiSet"
  },

  columns: [{
      name: "Kişi",
      template: {
        content: "{Klnad}"
      }
    }, {
      name: "Faaliyet",
      template: {
        content: "{Falyt}"
      }
    }, {
      name: "Süre",
      template: {
        content: {
          parts: ["Sure"],
          formatter: function(oValue) { // oValue is null that's the problem !!!!!!!  
            oValue = oValue + 2;
            return oValue;
          }
        }

      }
    }, {
      name: "Proje",
      template: {
        content: "{Proje}"
      }
    },

  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m facing a similar issue in some data binding use cases. The formatter function gets called with the initial data binding value which can be null or undefined. I circumvent this issue by ignoring calls of the formatter function by simple null and undefined checks.

Answer (score 3):

You should an array of objects instead of strings for the `parts`

```
parts: [
    { path: "Sure" }
]
```

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html